# Message parity check

Tags: c#, binary, crc, algebra, polynomial-math

Can someone help me out with implementing this sequence of calculations in C#?
[image]

Comment: How far have you got / what do you have so far, or having problems getting started?

Comment: Is that your homework?

Comment: The thing is... you take the 24bit id of the message you do the above calculations and end up with 24bits parity sequence. But the above instructuons seem very confusing

Comment: 1) "where k is 32 or 88"  Parity sequence is generated from the 24bit ID  which is 24bits long. So which are the "information bits"?
2) What is G(x) ? how it is calculated?
3) How is  x^24[M(x)] calculated?
4) How is R(x) calculated?

Comment: If this is homework please tag is as such. Also please show us what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: It is not my homework its part of a prgram i am writing that receives and decodes certain packets but now its time to check the parity. Is it me or the instructions are not very clear?

Comment: What is not very clear is your question. Are you actually asking us to implement this algorithm for you?

Comment: No i do not want you to do the work for me. Perhaps help me clear out the steps i should make. For example how is the expression x^24[M(x)] implemented

Comment: @redfrogsbinary So, you just want an explanation of what's going on -- that is, details on the question rather than an answer ? Don't hesitate to edit your question to state that if this is the case. It's hard to guess from your question as it stands now, and besides, SO answerers are generally wary of questions that seem to "outsource" (home)work to them with minimal effort.

Comment: FYI, this is an extract from http://diseqc.org.ua/projects/hard/adsb/ICAO%20Anx%2010-Aeronautical%20Telecommunications-Vol.4-Ed.3.2002.pdf (Aeronautical
Telecommunications - Surveillance Radar and
Collision Avoidance Systems).

Comment: Here is an implementation of the [CRC Calculation for Mode-S](http://jetvision.de/sbs/adsb/crc.htm) in Pascal.

Comment: What a terribly articulated dsecription of a parity check.

Comment: @Danra: It's not a simple parity check, it's a CRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem essentially describes a CRC with a 24-bit polynomial.

You can solve the problem simply using shift and XOR operations and a 24-bit (or larger) variable; no bigint required.

Recommended introductory reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check
- http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath458.htm
- http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt

Answer (score 0):

I took the opportunity to dabble with this.  Interpreting the equations in the context of an implementation in software is tricky because there are many ways in which the polynomials can be mapped to data structures in memory - and, I assume, you'll want the solution you produce to seamlessly inter-operate with other implementations.  In this context, it matters if your byte ordering is MSB or LSB first... it also matters if you align your bit-strings that aren't a multiple of 8 to the left or right.  It is worth noting that the polynomials are denoted in ascending powers of X - whereas one might assume, because the leftmost bit in a byte has maximum index, that the leftmost bit should correspond to the maximum power of X - but that's not the convention in use.

Essentially, there are two very different approaches to calculating CRCs using generator polynomials.  The first, and least efficient, is to use arbitrary precision arithmetic and modulo - as the posted extract suggests. A faster approach involves successive application of the polynomial and exclusive-or.

A implementation in Pascal can be found here: http://jetvision.de/sbs/adsb/crc.htm - translation to C# should prove trivial.

A more direct approach might involve encoding the message and the generator polynomial as System.Numerics.BigInteger objects (using C#/.Net 4.0) and calculate the parity bits exactly as the text above suggests - by finding the message modulo the polynomial - simply using the "%" operator on suitably encoded BigIntegers.  The only challenge here is in converting your message and parity bits to/from a format suitable for your application.